# Cannot access button in nib file (UI Testing iOS)

Tags: ios, nib, xcode-ui-testing, ui-testing, swift4.1

I am writing a UITest case for my view. The problem is I cannot access the button in my nib file view. I gave the accessibility identifier to the button as well but still cannot access it [Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRb3A.png)

I just want to tap on that reject button but accessibility identifier is not working for this. Here is my code for this

```
app.buttons["CancelRequest"].tap()
```

CancelRequest is Accessibility identifier. I also tried the below code because button is in a container view but no luck

```
let ContainerView = app.otherElements["RejectContainerView"]
let RejectButton = ContainerView.buttons.element(boundBy: 0)  
RejectButton.tap()
```

I also tried to record the screen as well which generated this code

```
app.buttons["dismiss"].tap()
```

The weird thing is the recording screen is generating the same code for the cancel button as well as you can see the cancel button in the image I provided

Comment: "have you tried by using "Reject" instead of "CancelRequest"

Comment: U mean to say access it by the button name. I did it already bro it didn't work the test case fails

Comment: May be you are accessing button before its nib loaded in view.

Comment: Before tapping on button I check the static label on the nib to make sure it is loaded

Comment: Okay then you can say Xcode to generate statements by running XCUITests and starting recording of UItests, Xcode automatically generates statements for events in UITests, along with accessing elements.

Comment: U didn't read the post carefully bro I have already mention that the recording is generating the same code for the cancel button as well as for the reject button so it get confused which button to tap you can see the cancel button in the image I provided

Comment: What happens when you tap the `RejectButton` in the `ContainerView`? PS: Variables should start with lower case characters...

Comment: The program cannot find the element and it fails the test case. The code executes but he cannot find the ui element on the screen so he can test it

Comment: okay then try changing view's label name too, viewCancelButton , and viewRejectButton and then try a recording if you don't mind

Comment: It's still not working. Can anybody give solution for this still stuck on this for 2 days

Answer (score 0):

It worked after disabling the accessibility identifier of button and enabling it again. I think this is a bug it's very weird behavior of XCTEST case

I tried to duplicate the same results with another xib and yes this is a problem in XCTEST case sometimes you cannot access xib buttons you have to disable and enable the accessibility identifier several times and sometimes if that doesn't work then simply do this

```
sleep(2)
app.buttons["submit"].tap()
```

Just put sleep before tapping the button this is apple's recommended way really weird